# How to exclude this pattern in bash scripting?

Tags: bash, shell, scripting, grep, pattern-matching

I want to match the pattern using SED and/or GREP which can exclude some alphabets.

```
## This code will match the alphabet, how to exclude them?
## Here, the variable is string which we are matching.


argument=$2
grep "$(sed 's/./&.*/g' <<< "$argument")" "$file_name"
shift ;;

# Possible output

$ sh match_the_pattern.sh -c aeiou words.txt

cyts
flybs
glhs
lphs
mrhs
nmphs

# As you can see, it is posting the words but execluding the characters from given string.
```

Comment: `sed -n "/$(sed 's/./&.*/g' <<< "$argument")/{s/[${argument}]//g;p}" "$file_name"`

Comment: Your questions are getting worse. Please see [ask].

Comment: sed -n "/$(sed 's/./&.*/g' <<< "$argument")/{s/[${argument}]//g;p}" "$file_name" this is not giving the correct results.

Answer (score 0):

You mean something like that?

remove_chars.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
sed "s/[$1]//g" "$2"
```

USAGE:

```
remove_chars.sh chars file.txt
```

Example:

```
remove_chars.sh aeiou file.txt
```

Caution: Not all characters work, but letters and numbers!